# VirtualBox USB Wifi Disconnecting

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, virtualbox

**What I'm trying to do:**
I am attempting to run a continuous ping as a proof of concept for a larger project

**Overview of how I'm trying to do it:**
I have a machine running in VirtualBox. 
To this machine I am passing a USB wireless network adapter. 
I'm connecting this to a wireless network. 
Over this network I am running a continuous ping.

**What is happening:**
This ping works for a while and then stops.  Sometimes restarting the network stack helps sometimes it doesnt. 
The ping runs continuously from the host machine.

**OS, Hardware and Version:** 
I didn't include the version of or OS above because I've used a variety.

As a host I have used two different machines running Windows 7 and WES 7. These have Virtual box 5.0.14 and 5.0.10 installed respectively both with the corresponding Extension pack for their version.

USB wireless adapters are specific to the host. The hosts are running an RealTek rtl8187 and Ralink rt2800 chip sets respectively.

As a guest I have used OpenWRT 15.05 on both hosts, On the Windows 7 host I have also run Lubuntu 15.10 and WES 7 SP1.

In all these cases I have experienced the same problem.

Does anyone know if there is a known problem with USB wifi through Virtual Box or even better if there is a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Why not connect adapter to host and then just bridge mode to the guest ?

Comment: For my end goal to work I'll need the adapter to appear as a Wireless interface.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

What worked for me was to go to Device Manager and find the adapter you're capturing in VirtualBox.  Click on Properties -> Power Management and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

Make sure your Guest is shut down so the adapter shows up in Device Manager.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I had tried that to solve the issue and it didn't.  for that reason and others this project never got off the ground.